# SQL SERVER QUERY to get the Number of Distinct column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

This is the sample expected result table

[image]

As you can see I have a list of tenant with corresponding Area. I need to create a column 'Count' where it will count the number of distinct Area in the given TENANT. For example tenant 'CMBINA13' has two distinct Area. So it should output 2 in the count column, same with the next tenant example having 1 distinct area only.

Here's what I have initially got

```
select tenantcode ,  b.name , AreaSqm  ,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AreaSqm) AS 'Count'
from    TENANT
```

and it gives a logically incorrect output like this

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Count is an aggregate function so have you tried grouping by?

Comment: it will consolidate the tenantcode as one, i need to show each detail of tenantcode, I just did not show the sales column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to count `DISTINCT areasqm`, but you can't do this with `COUNT .. OVER`, and you can't do it neither with `GROUP BY tenantcode , name , AreaSqm` directly. So, one solution is to count `DISTINCT areasqm` in a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT
  t.tenantcode , name , AreaSqm  , c.areaCount
FROM TENANT AS t
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT tenantcode, COUNT(DISTINCT areasqm) AS areaCount
   FROM tenant 
   GROUP BY tenantcode
) AS c ON t.tenantcode = c.tenantcode;
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: I'll try this! So count distinct is not applicable in partitioning...?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer - Yes, you will get an error : `Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

```
select tenantcode,  b.name, AreaSqm ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT areasqm) OVER (PARTITION BY tenantcode) AS acnt
from TENANT;
```

Then you can do this without an aggregation/join.  You simply need to enumerate the values and count where they are equal to 1:

```
select tenantcode, name, AreaSqm,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by tenantcode) as acnt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tenantcode, areasqm order by tenantcode) as seqnum
      from TENANT t
     ) t
```